# How to iterate faces given a 3D convex hull of points

Tags: 3d, geometry, point-cloud-library, convex-hull, point-clouds

I've used a library function that returns the 3D convex hull of a point cloud in a list, but how do I find all the combinations of points that form the faces of the hull?

Comment: Do the points have any duplications, or are they always a multiple of 3?  If so, it may be giving you triangles in sets of 3 vertices.

Comment: If you are using PCL, then there are two versions of the reconstruct method: one that does return the polygonal faces and one that does not.

Comment: All **combinations** of points forming the hull, or just all the points?